# Как вызвать класс после обработки кнопки?

Tags: java, swing

Добрый день!

Как мне сделать так, чтобы класс main вызывал класс GUI

*GUI.main(args);*

именно после того, как в классе GUI слушатель кнопки выполнит свой код?

Вставляю код класса GUI

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

public static String team_1;
public static String team_2;

public GUI() {
    setTitle("**");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 635);
    setLocation(300, 50);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    createGUI();
}

public void createGUI() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    add(panel);
    panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    /*class Imaging extends JPanel {

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("icon.png");

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 180, 20, this);
        }
    }


    Imaging imaging = new Imaging();*/

    JTextField team_name_1 = new JTextField("Команда 1");
    panel.add(team_name_1);
    team_name_1.setBounds(20,30,150,30);

    JTextField team_name_2 = new JTextField("Команда 2");
    panel.add(team_name_2);
    team_name_2.setBounds(230, 30, 150, 30);

    JLabel created_by = new JLabel();
    created_by.setText("Created_by_NikiToZz");
    panel.add(created_by);
    created_by.setBounds(133,580,180,30);

    JButton go = new JButton();
    go.setText("GO");
    go.setActionCommand("GO was pressed!");
    panel.add(go);
    go.setBounds(110,80,180,30);

    go.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            team_1 = team_name_1.getText();
            team_2 = team_name_2.getText();
        }
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            GUI gui =  new GUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Здесь обсуждали подобное, посмотрите может подойдет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803428/how-to-load-a-java-gui-class-from-a-main-class

Comment: Там ответ - это то, что у меня уже есть..